# Which software design patterns do common GUI frameworks exhibit?

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, frameworks

I have been a python programmer 7+ years now, and been designing with PyQt for 3+ years... But I am not a classically trained Comp Sci. major. More recently I have been learning [Go](http://golang.org) and been actively following the [Golang-nuts discussion list](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/topics?pli=1) which is filled with extremely intelligent developers. From this discussion group, I have seen many references to software design patterns, such as Observer, Reactor, etc. Again because I am not a CS major, I never really learned all of this terminology and theory, but it made me wonder...

**What design patterns do common GUI frameworks like Qt, wx, GTK exhibit?**

I have a feeling like its a mixture of patterns for different components, such as the event loop vs signal/slots or binding vs Key-value observing, and so on. I would love to hear an explanation or generalization about how these software patterns map to the traditional components of these frameworks.

As a bit of a secondary element to this question: Are there GUI frameworks that try and take a completely different pattern approach to a GUI solution? Does Cocoa/objective-c use the same event loop patterns as these others?

**Update**
To help narrow down the focus of my question, and based on the answer by @HDDimon, I am mainly wondering about Behavior Patterns (communication):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Behavioral_patterns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good day. I think the best answer you will find in Martin Fowler article [GUI Architectures](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController).

from this article:

> **Model View Controller** Probably the widest quoted pattern in UI development is Model View Controller (MVC) - it's also the most
>   misquoted. I've lost count of the times I've seen something described
>   as MVC which turned out to be nothing like it. Frankly a lot of the
>   reason for this is that parts of classic MVC don't really make sense
>   for rich clients these days. But for the moment we'll take a look at
>   its origins.
>
> **At the heart of MVC**, and the idea that was the most **influential to later frameworks**, is what I call **Separated Presentation**. The
>   idea behind Separated Presentation is to **make a clear division
>   between domain objects that model our perception of the real world,
>   and presentation objects that are the GUI elements we see on the
>   screen**. Domain objects should be completely self contained and work
>   without reference to the presentation, they should also be able to
>   support multiple presentations, possibly simultaneously. This approach
>   was also an important part of the Unix culture, and continues today
>   allowing many applications to be manipulated through both a graphical
>   and command-line interface.

According to this article, the best types of patterns for division between any kinds of components is Structural Patterns.

from "[Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)" by The "Gang of Four": Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides. (I really want recommend you to read this awesome book)

- Structure Patterns:

  - Adapter
  - Bridge
  - Composite
  - Decorator
  - Facade
  - Flyweight
  - Proxy

But in any kind of frameworks you can see mix from several types of patterns: Creational patterns, Structural patterns, Behavioral patterns.

I had found a [relational diagram between patterns](http://nasir.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/design_patterns1.jpg) from Design Patterns book, it may be helpful for everyday using.

**UPD: Great SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns) added.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info. I'm very familiar with MVC as its pretty common to other frameworks as well. I will definitely check out your references. But, I was also hoping someone would focus their answer more specifically on the popular GUI frameworks and their communication methods. The event loop, signals slots, kvo, message/event passing, etc. I could obviously read a book on general design patterns, but I wanted to hear direct and specific examples to these GUI frameworks. Any extra info?